# Correct notation for variable substitution?

Tags: notation

Is this notation conventional to indicate that $M$ should be replaced with 2?

$$  \left. \frac{(D + M - 1)!}{(D - 1)!M!} \right|_{M = 2} $$

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: It's usually only used in calculus, but I think most people would understand it.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!